# how to make two objects on one screen

Tags: batch-file

I am make the old game breakout,but I have ran into a problem.
The problem is that I can't get the ball to be able to be on the same plane as the block

```
    @echo off
    title breakout
    :load
    for /l %%g in (0,1,500) do set f%%g=#
    for /l %%g in (0,1,500) do set d%%g=#
    for /l %%g in (0,1,500) do set g%%g=#

    set current_pixel=ß
    set p=4
    set t=5
    set ball=ø
    set q=34
    set scoreyou=0
    set run=0
    :play
    set f%p%=%current_pixel%
    set f%t%=%current_pixel%
    set d%q%=%ball%
    cls
    echo     %scoreyou%
echo. Þ%d1%%d2%%d3%%d4%%d5%%d6%%d7%%d8%%d9%%d10%%d11%%d12%%d13%%d14%%d15%%d16%%d17%%d18%%d19%%d20%Ý
echo. Þ%d21%%d22%%d23%%d24%%d25%%d26%%d27%%d28%%d29%%d30%%d31%%d32%%d33%%d34%%d35%%d36%%d37%%d38%%d39%%d40%Ý
echo. Þ%d41%%d42%%d43%%d44%%d45%%d46%%d47%%d48%%d49%%d50%%d51%%d52%%d53%%d54%%d55%%d56%%d57%%d58%%d59%%d60%Ý
echo. Þ%d61%%d62%%d63%%d64%%d65%%d66%%d67%%d68%%d69%%d70%%d71%%d72%%d73%%d74%%d75%%d76%%d77%%d78%%d79%%d80%Ý
echo. Þ%d81%%d82%%d83%%d84%%d85%%d56%%d66%%d76%%d86%%d96%Ý
echo. Þ%d81%%d18%%d28%%d38%%d48%%d58%%d68%%d78%%d88%%d98%Ý
echo. Þ%d101%%d20%%d30%%d40%%d50%%d60%%d70%%d80%%d90%%d100%Ý
echo. Þ%f1%%f2%%f3%%f4%%f5%%f6%%f7%%f8%%f9%%f10%Ý
echo. Þ%d11%%d21%%d30%%d40%%d50%%d60%%d70%%d80%%d90%%d100%Ý
echo.  ßßßßßßßßßß

if %scoreyou% EQU 10 goto win
set d%q%=
```

the top four rows of %d% is the number that should be the block, but that has to be shared with %ball% and #. This causes a problem because I can't figure out how to have both and let the ball transition between planes.

Comment: The code you have provided does not seem to be completely relevant to your issue - is this code all you have written so far?

Comment: no this is the main set up with the problem I can give you all if it.